# What is the full list of tools and purposes in A Dark Room?

Tags: a-dark-room

In the middle column of the room, there is a bunch of supplies. What is the full list, and what does each one do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind knowing what's ahead of you then go to :
[Wiki of the supplies](http://adarkroom.wikia.com/wiki/Avatar_upgrades).

There is a detailed explanation as to what each building does. You can also find a lot of other information about the game there.

I would like to advise you ***not*** to go there though, as it will take some fun out of the exploring and waiting for unknown things to happen.

Comment: Nice, but I was looking for the supplies, not the buildings (eg. bone spear, torch etc.)

Comment: Changed the link to the supplies link :)